# How did New Horizons take such well-lit pictures of Pluto?

Tags: light, pluto, artificial-satellite

The photos of Pluto from New Horizons are truly beautiful.

But considering that Pluto is so far away from its nearest start - our Sun - how is it so well lit up?

Did the New Horizons have a massive flash mounted on its camera to illuminate the planet or is there just a lot of ambient light in space?

I'm really curious.

[image: Pluto]

Comment: A flashbulb suitable for lighting up Pluto would bear more than a passing resemblance to [Tsar Bomba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba)

Comment: A combination of sensitive detectors, aperture and exposure. Also a lot of post processing (it is a composite from more than one sensor)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's brighter on Pluto than you think.

NASA developed a tool called [Pluto time](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-lets-you-experience-pluto-time-with-new-custom-tool/), which tells you when at your place the ambient light conditions are similar to the ones on Pluto.  This occurs when the Sun is only 2° below the horizon!  That's quite shortly after sunset, and considerably before the end of civil twilight, which is when it's 6° below.

All of these photos were taken at local "Pluto time":

[image: Pluto time]

Pluto time, according to NASA.  [Source: NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/nasa-lets-you-experience-pluto-time-with-new-custom-tool/)

To answer your question: all it takes is a slightly longer exposure time / larger aperture / higher gain (what photographers may call ISO) than taking photos closer to the Sun.  It's easily bright enough for outdoor activities (except perhaps on a cloudy evening and/or in a dense forest, but neither should be common beyond the orbit of Neptune), so have fun [glacier hiking](http://www.nature.com/news/nitrogen-glaciers-flow-on-pluto-1.18062) on Pluto!

Comment: Yep! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Intensity_in_the_Solar_System

Comment: That's so cool.   It makes perfect sense but it had never occurred to me.